# can annotation-config work in java application project?

Tags: java, spring

I defined a classloader and added all my libraries， then I defined a ApplicationContext, I tried to getBean with ApplicationContext from a class in external jar, here are my key codes:

```
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(beanPath) {
            @Override
            protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
                super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
                reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);
                reader.setBeanClassLoader(classLoader);
            }
        };
```

I tried to getBean like this:

```
AswanService instance = (AswanService)context.getBean("aswanService", AswanService.class);
```

But the question is, if I define the target class which properties have setter/getter methods, the instance object can be injected with the two properties, the class defines like this:

```
    public class AswanServiceImpl implements AswanService {
        SpringInjectFaker springInjectFaker;

        ItemDO itemDO;

        public AswanResponse request(AswanRequest aswanRequest) {
            springInjectFaker.fake();

            AswanResponse response = new AswanResponse();
            response.setName("response: " + aswanRequest.getName() + "; " + itemDO.getItemId());
            return response;
        }

        public SpringInjectFaker getSpringInjectFaker() {
            return springInjectFaker;
        }

        public void setSpringInjectFaker(SpringInjectFaker springInjectFaker) {
            this.springInjectFaker = springInjectFaker;
        }

        public ItemDO getItemDO() {
            return itemDO;
        }

        public void setItemDO(ItemDO itemDO) {
            this.itemDO = itemDO;
        }
    }
```

but if it is defined with autowired annotation, it doesn't work:

```
    public class AswanServiceImpl implements AswanService {
        @Autowired
        SpringInjectFaker springInjectFaker;

        @Autowired
        ItemDO itemDO;

        public AswanResponse request(AswanRequest aswanRequest) {
            springInjectFaker.fake();

            AswanResponse response = new AswanResponse();
            response.setName("response: " + aswanRequest.getName() + "; " + itemDO.getItemId());
            return response;
        }
    }
```

instance = context.getBean("aswanService", AswanService.class), instance is injected but its two properties itemDO and springInjectFaker are both null.

I tried to add  config, but didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="aswanService" class="com.taobao.qa.perf.tr.AswanServiceImpl" autowire="byName"></bean>
    <bean id="springInjectFaker" class="com.taobao.qa.perf.tr.SpringInjectFakerImp" autowire="byName"></bean>
    <bean id="itemDO" class="com.taobao.qa.perf.tr.ItemDO" autowire="byName">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="1"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="2"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My project is java project, I run the program in main function （public static void main(String[] args)）, thanks for your help ~~~

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out.

Add  or  are both ok.

I come to a problem that when I add any the configuration above, the ide throw a exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from URL [file:xxxxxxx/beans.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@1d89c040] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.alibaba.middleware.Application$2.<init>(Application.java:159)
    at com.alibaba.middleware.Application.main(Application.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@1d89c040] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No attributes are implemented
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99)
    ... 22 more
```

so I gave up, I just tried again, until I found that adding two args in VM options can solve this exception, and my problem is also solved. I don't know why, and I'm still studying.

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please to add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.taobao.qa" />` to your config

Answer (score 0):

**mvc:annotation-driven** is used for enabling the Spring MVC components with its default configurations.

**If you dont include mvc:annotation-driven also your MVC application would work if you have used the *context:component-scan* for creating the beans or defined the beans in your XML file**

**context:component-scan** element in the spring configuration file would eliminate the need for declaring all the beans in the XML files. Look at the below declaration in your spring configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.controller"/>
```

The above declaration in the spring application configuration file would scan the classes inside the specified package and create the beans instance. Note that it could create beans only if that class is annotated with correct annotations. The following are the annotations scanned by this element:

- @Component
- @Repository
- @Service
- @Controller

Comment: My project is a java application project not web application.  And I tried to add component-scan configuration. but it doesn't work too...